# Passing Array of sObject to Apex from Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-experience

I am trying to pass array of sObject to Apex controller in Lightning but it is not working.

```
createOwner : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('$$$$$$Test: '+ component.get("v.ownerList"));
    var action = component.get("c.createAdditionalOwner");
    action.setParams({
        "newOwnerList": component.get("v.ownerList")

    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            console.log('$$$$$Check: '+ a.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

newOwnerList is List of Record and this is the parameter used in Apex method.
ownerList is Array of Account used in component.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String createAdditionalOwner(List<Visit_Owner_Institution__c> newOwnerList){
    System.debug('$$$$$Check: '+ newOwnerList);
    return 'Success';

}
```

Comment: What is the error you are facing?.can you also update the question with the markup code for the attribute

Comment: Also the apex part

Comment: In apex I am just trying to debug the list. But in Debug log debugs are not creating.

Comment: When I am trying to pass a simple string then it is working fine

Comment: Only getting issue when trying to pass Array of sObject

Comment: Are there any errors? Can you please share them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript controller stores the list as `Object[]` and not your as `sObject[]`.

Since you say when you pass a string it works fine, there are two workarounds for it.

**1. Json string as an attribute**
You can convert the sobject list in javascript to a json string and then deserialize it in apex using `JSON.deserialize`and covert it to the required sobject type.

[Find more here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm)

**2. Use Object[] as an argument in apex** You can pass the list as you are passing it from the javascript controller but instead of using `List<Visit_Owner_Institution__c> newOwnerList` in your apex code you can use `Object[] newOwnerList` and then typecast that list into the sObject type `Visit_Owner_Institution__c` in apex.

[More here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000Xe5lQAC)